# Gulp watch task runs once, then hangs on the 2nd run

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch, tslint

I have some gulp tasks to run my TSLint checks for a project.  I have a task to only watch the newly changed files and run the checks for these when they change (upon file save).  Currently when I run the `watchTS` task, it will run and work fine upon the first file I save/change.  Upon the next file change it will run the task but not actually complete or do any TSLint validation.

**Gulp Output**

```
[09:49:34] Starting 'watchTS'...
[09:49:35] Finished 'watchTS' after 692 ms
[09:49:36] Starting 'tslint:newer'...
Running - tslint:newer
[09:49:36] [gulp-tslint] error example.controller.ts[13, 8]: unused variable: 'x'
[09:49:36] Finished 'tslint:newer' after 738 ms
[09:53:38] Starting 'tslint:newer'...
Running - tslint:newer
```

It runs once, and finds an error.  I do something to make it run again, and it never finishes the task or runs TSLint.

Here are the relevant gulp tasks

```js
var BIN = "bin";
var TYPE_SCRIPT_FILES = ["app/**/*.ts"];
var TYPE_SCRIPT_CONFIG = tslint({
    rulesDirectory: "tslint-rules/"
});
var TYPE_SCRIPT_REPORT = tslint.report("prose", {
    emitError: false,
    reportLimit: 50
});

gulp.task("tslint:newer", function () {
    console.log("Running - tslint:newer");
    return gulp.src(TYPE_SCRIPT_FILES)
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(newer(BIN))
        .pipe(TYPE_SCRIPT_CONFIG)
        .pipe(TYPE_SCRIPT_REPORT)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(BIN));
});

gulp.task("watchTS", [], function () {
    gulp.watch(TYPE_SCRIPT_FILES, ["tslint:newer"]);
});
```